# Should I Add Full Stops/Periods to My Errors?

Tags: exception, error-handling

This may sound like a stupid question but it's causing some disagreement among my team. Should you add full stops (that's periods for you programmers over the pond) to my errors?

Which is better?

```
throw new \Exception( 'Failed to delete ' . $model_name );
```

or

```
throw new \Exception( 'Failed to delete ' . $model_name . '.' );
```

Problems arise when you need to concatenate multiple messages so I guess it's just a matter of consistency but is there a standard way of doing this?

Comment: It is a question related to user experience. Post at : http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I always think that you should follow the industry leaders when trying to decide.  For example, on Windows, MS tend to use full stops in all their messages, therefore I do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is more suited for ux.stackexchange.com.

Comment: See http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/18671

Answer (score 6):

If it falls nicely into the definition of a sentence it probably requires a full stop.

> A grammatical unit that is syntactically independent and has a subject
>   that is expressed or, as in imperative sentences, understood and a
>   predicate that contains at least one finite verb.

Comment: But then you have a problem when trying to join two messages and have to check whether they end in full stops which isn't very elegant. Surely a single standard is better?

Comment: @voidstate: I don't understand your problem with joining error messages together if they have full stops.  This comment is three sentences concatenated together, and reads just fine.  Why would naively concatenating full-stop-terminated error messages in the same way cause problems?